# Switching the names of two files

Tags: powershell, renaming

I'm working on a script to change the logon background of the computers. I've got it to do everything I need but I'm trying to make the script more efficient, because as it stands, after a new one is chosen, a function I created called `OrderNames` is called to rename everything to random, then rename them background1, 2, 3, and so on. Here's a snippet of what I'm working with:

```
Function OrderNames #Renames everything to a format better than random numbers
{
    $FileNames = GCI $BGPath -exclude $BGOld
    $FileNames | ForEach-Object -process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$Get-Random).jpg" }
    $OrderNames = GCI $BGPath -exclude $BGOld
    $OrderNames | ForEach-Object -begin { $count = 1 } -process 
    { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "background$count.jpg"; $count++ }
}

$Path = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds"
$BGOld = GCI $BGPath "backgrounddefault.jpg"     #Store current background name
$BGFiles = GCI $BGPath -exclude $BGOld           #Get all other images
$BGNew = $BGFiles[(get-random -max ($BGFiles.count)] #Select new image
Rename-Item $BGOld.FullName "$(Get-Random)-$($_.Name).jpg" 
Rename-Item $BGNew.FullName "backgrounddefault.jpg"
OrderNames
```

That works fine and dandy, but I'd like to be able to simply switch the names of `$BGOld` and `$BGNew`. Back in college with C I could create a temp variable, store BGNew to it, make BGNew equal BGOld and then make BGOld equal temp. But when I create a temp variable with the value of BGOld, it doesn't work. In fact, the variables don't seem to change with the rename function, and setting one equal to the other results in a

> Cannot rename because item at  does not exist.

Fine, so I tried setting just the name of the file to a variable with `Select basename`, but I get an error about

> cannot index into an object of type system.io.fileinfo.

Also, I tried `$BGOld.FullName = $BGNew.FullName`, tried that with `Rename-Item` and a few others I can't remember right now.

I tried to copy the item name but this didn't work either. I'm hoping it's not something simple that I've overlooked.

**TL;DR**
Is it possible to copy the name of a file into a temp variable, so that when I rename the files, I can copy the name of the temp variable back over to the "old" one to avoid renaming everything? Or even better, can I just switch the filenames?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question: Rename first file to a temporary name, rename second file to first file's name, then rename temporary file to second file's name.

Comment: Renaming the file on disk to something random before renaming the new file to the name of the old *is* the file-system equivalent of what you do in memory in the C variable swap you described

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I tried doing that but it wouldn't let me do it-when I try to I get errors about the filename not existing, or even better, path is null.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I understand, but it will not allow me to store the name to a temp variable and then apply the temp variable to the name of the old one.

Comment: @user6111573 please see the answer I've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something similar in PowerShell. The "algorithm" for this is basically the same as you describe for C:

1. Rename the old to something temporary
2. Rename the new to the name of the old
3. Rename the old to the name of the new

So the only pieces of information we need to keep track of is the old and new names + the temporary file name.

```
# Grab the current background and pick the new one
$BGPath = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds"
$CurrentBG = Get-Item (Join-Path $BGPath -ChildPath 'backgrounddefault.jpg')
$NewBG     = Get-ChildItem $BGPath -Filter *.jpg -Exclude $CurrentBG.Name |Get-Random
# Store the current name of the new background in a variable
$NewBGName = $NewBG.Name

# Now comes the swap operation
# 1. Rename old file to something completely random, but keep a reference to it with -PassThru
$OldBG = $CurrentBG |Rename-Item -NewName $([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()) -PassThru

# 2. Rename new file to proper name
$NewBG |Rename-Item -NewName 'backgrounddefault.jpg'

# 3. And finally rename the old background back to the name previously used by the new background
$OldBG |Rename-Item -NewName $NewBGName
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't initializing my temp name properly, and had no idea about using [System.IO.Path] like you listed. Wasn't Piping into Rename-Item like I should have either. Forgive my ignorance, haven't learned all the ins and outs of powershell yet just yet.

Comment: @user6111573 Don't worry too much, we all live and learn :) Please note that piping a collection to `Get-Random` returns a random item from the collection as well, bit more concise than calculating a random index

Answer (score 0):

Check it out.  Using variables to refer to files, and then swapping the variables.

```
${c:file1.txt},${c:file2.txt} = ${c:file2.txt},${c:file1.txt}
```